# Why is my menu font changing size when I go to one page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I'm having a problem where the site menu on the left hand of the page gets bigger on one of the pages. On this certain page, I have a table and a script editor web part in the table. I think it has something to do with the width percentage on my script editor. But if I make the percentage lower than 100% it changes the table and makes the other columns smaller. I've tried changing it so the height is specified at 100% but it just looks the exact same. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]
In this picture the menu font size is weirdly large compared to how the menu is in the rest of the website.

[image]
Here is the first part of my code. The rest is just a table with some pictures and links in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your custom HTML is repeating some basic HTML elements that are already present on the page.

If you were creating a standalone web page, then yes, your structure is correct, you would want the root `<html>` tag, a `<head>` with your `<style>` block in it, and then a `<body>`.  But in the case of inserting HTML into a SharePoint page, SharePoint is already generating the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, so you don't need to.  Everything you are adding to the page will be inside the existing `<body>`.

In your case, the font size issue is happening because in your custom CSS, you are applying the font size to the `<body>`, which in this case is *not* the `<body>` in your custom HTML, but the true `<body>` which has been generated by SharePoint, and which *the Quicklaunch menu is inside*.  So since the Quicklaunch is inside the main `<body>`, your custom font styles are getting applied to it as well as your custom content.

What you need to do is remove the `<html>` and `<head>` tags from your custom HTML (the `<style>` block will be just fine on its own), and change the `<body>` to be just a regular `<div>`, and give that `<div>` either an ID or a CSS class that you can use in a CSS selector so you can apply your font styles to it.